# Use PDF vector graphics in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

I have PDF image assets from an iOS project that I need to add to an Android Studio project.  Is it possible to add PDFs to Android studio, or do I have to use an external converter like Gimp or Illustrator to convert the assets to SVG/PSD/XML? ([Google's Android vector graphics documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#apilevel))  If so, are there some best practices for doing so? Asking because my attempts to do this so far have resulted in low-quality assets.

Comment: "Is it possible to add PDFs to Android studio" -- if you wish to create drawable resources from them (e.g., for button icons), then the answer is no. "do I have to use an external converter like Gimp or Illustrator to convert the assets to SVG/PSD/XML?" -- yes.

Comment: Try PaintCode app for Mac if you want to easily convert vector PDFs to Android Vector Drawable.